# Target names with CMake ExternalProject for cross platform libraries dependency

Tags: c++, compilation, cmake, cross-platform

I'm trying to create a `CMakeLists` that will automatically download and compile a library and `link` it to another project, on Windows and Linux.
For that, I use `ExternalProject_Add`. The download and compilation part are fine, however, on windows the library created is called `zlibd.lib` while on linux it's called `zlib.a`.

Here is my code :

```
if (NOT Zlib_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "Zlib has not been found. Therefore it will automatically be downloaded during the compilation process.")
    ExternalProject_Add(Zlib
        SOURCE_DIR "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib"
        BINARY_DIR "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib-build"
        INSTALL_DIR "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/deps/zlib-install"
        GIT_REPOSITORY "${git_protocol}://github.com/madler/zlib.git"
        GIT_TAG "50893291621658f355bc5b4d450a8d06a563053d"
        CMAKE_ARGS
            -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>
            -DINSTALL_BIN_DIR:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>/bin
            -DINSTALL_INC_DIR:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>/include
            -DINSTALL_LIB_DIR:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>/lib
            -DINSTALL_MAN_DIR:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>/share/man
            -DINSTALL_PKGCONFIG_DIR:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>/share/pkgconfig)
    ExternalProject_Get_Property(Zlib install_dir)
    set(ZLIB_LIB_DIR ${install_dir}/lib)
    set(ZLIB_INC_DIR ${install_dir}/include)
    set(ZLIB_BIN_DIR ${install_dir}/bin)

    add_library(zlib STATIC IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${ZLIB_LIB_DIR}/zlibd.lib)

endif()
```

However, here I hardcoded the library name for windows, so when I want to compile it on Linux, the library is not found.

How can I make it find the proper library name, based on the platform (if possible without hardcoding them)?

Thank you.

**Edit:** Is it possible to get from ExternalProject the targets? (with getproperty, or something similar?) Or eventually do it the other way, force ExternalProject to output the targets with a given name?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you would normally use [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html):

```
find_library(ZLIB_LIBRARY NAMES foo PATHS ${ZLIB_LIB_DIR})
add_library(zlib STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(zlib PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION "${ZLIB_LIBRARY}")
```

This way, it would look for `libzlib.a` on Linux and `zlib.lib` on Windows.

However it appears that the names of your libraries are quite specific and do not follow an apparent naming scheme, which makes it difficult for CMake to find the library automatically (without hard-coding the name).

Another option you might be interested in is to couple `ExternalProject_Add` with the ability of CMake to manage dependencies, as is done in [this project](https://github.com/Crascit/DownloadProject) and described in [this blog article](https://crascit.com/2015/07/25/cmake-gtest/). If you follow this approach you could just use the `zlib` target defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` of the project you import.

Comment: find_library does not work with externalproject projects